# How do I display array elements in Lua?

Tags: sdk, lua, coronasdk

I'm having an issue displaying the elements of an array in Lua programming language. Basically, i created an array with 3 elements, and i'm trying to display its contents in a for loop on the corona sdk emulator. What happens is that if i display the individual array elements (without the loop), they display fine; as soon as I put them in a for loop, nothing shows up on the screen anymore

this is my code:

```
myText = {"hello", "world", "there"}

for i = 1, myText do
     local myText = display.newText( myText[i], 0, 0, native.systemFont, 35 )
end
```

Comment: Don't you mean `for i = 1, #myText do` ?

Answer (score 14):

Why not just print the table in "table.concat" function?

```
myText = {"hello", "world", "there"}
print(table.concat(myText,", "))
```

> hello, world, there

Answer (score 11):

Here is a function I wrote to list the items in a table (corona calls arrays as "tables"). It is similar to PHP's print_r, so I called it print_r

You can call it as:

```
print_r(myTable)
```

Function:

```
function print_r(arr, indentLevel)
    local str = ""
    local indentStr = "#"

    if(indentLevel == nil) then
        print(print_r(arr, 0))
        return
    end

    for i = 0, indentLevel do
        indentStr = indentStr.."\t"
    end

    for index,value in pairs(arr) do
        if type(value) == "table" then
            str = str..indentStr..index..": \n"..print_r(value, (indentLevel + 1))
        else 
            str = str..indentStr..index..": "..value.."\n"
        end
    end
    return str
end
```

Comment: That sir made my day, simple and elegant!

Comment: I'm having a devil of a time trying to debug a mod for Don't Starve Together: The LUA interpreter there throws a hissy fit every time I dare try to concatenate things like "boolean", "userdata", etc (as happens when print_r-ing all kinds of interesting tables). Is there any simple way to amend the above function? Do I have to write cases for every possible type?

Answer (score 10):

What happens when you change your loop to this:

```
for i = 1, #myText do
    local myText = display.newText( myText[i], 0, 0, native.systemFont, 35 )
end
```

Or this:

```
for i, v in ipairs(myText) do
    local myText = display.newText( v, 0, 0, native.systemFont, 35 )
end
```

Comment: I was missing the # sign in front of the array, that worked thank you very much for your help Alex

Comment: Would it be possible to transform this into an answer?

Comment: phresnel, what do you mean? This *is* an answer.

Comment: @Alex he probably meant: "accepted answer"