# Getting a part of a list or table in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I know it's very easy to do in Python: `someList[1:2]`
But how do you this in Lua? That code gives me a syntax error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [`unpack`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-unpack) function built into Lua can do this job for you:

> Returns the elements from the given table.

You can also use

```
x, y = someList[1], someList[2]
```

for the same results. But this method can not be applied to varying length of [lua-table](/questions/tagged/lua-table).

### Usage

```
table.unpack (list [, i [, j]])
```

Returns the elements from the given table. This function is equivalent to

```
return list[i], list[i+1], ···, list[j]
```

By default, `i` is *1* and `j` is **`#list`**.

A [codepad](http://codepad.org/8zGPjX1g) link to show the working of the same.

Comment: Notice that the square bracket in the usage part means the i & j are optional ! Take me a while to understand.

Answer (score 23):

```
{unpack(someList, from_index, to_index)}
```

But table indexes will be started from `1`, not from `from_index`

Answer (score 9):

The exact equivalent to [the Python](https://repl.it/repls/DeepSufficientMenus)

```
someList = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
subList = someList[1:2]
print( subList )
```

[in Lua](https://repl.it/repls/WebbedIdleCell) is

```
someList = { 'a', 'b', 'c' , 'd' }
subList = { unpack( someList, 2, 2 ) }
print( unpack(subList) )
```

The key thing is that `unpack` returns ["multiple results"](https://www.lua.org/pil/5.1.html) which is *not* a table, so to get a list (aka table) in Lua you need to "tablify" the result with `{` and `}`.

However, you cannot print a *table* in Lua, but you can print *multiple results* so to get meaningful output, you need to unpack it again.

So unlike Python which mimics multiple returns using lists, Lua *truly* has them.

---

**Nb** in later versions of Lua `unpack` becomes `table.unpack`

Comment: printing the unpacked list did not work for me - it only printed the first element - but [table.concat(subList, ", "))](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50111596/2550406) is nice.

Comment: @lucidbrot which Lua version?

Comment: 5.3.5 on windows. (Though it's well possible that I have made some mistake and that's why it did not work) Edit: Yeah if I use your example in a single file, that works. Just treat my comment as help for others who make mistakes they don't find :)