# How to display 2D array in Lua

Tags: arrays, lua

This works:

```
mt = {}          -- create the matrix
    for i=1,5 do
     mt[i] = {}     -- create a new row
      for j=1,3 do
        mt[i][j] = j
        print(i,j)
      end
    end
```

but this does not

```
mt = {}          -- create the matrix
    for i=1,5 do
     mt[i] = {}     -- create a new row
      for j=1,3 do
        mt[i][j] = j
        print(i,j)
        print mt([i][j])
      end
    end
```

and gives the error

```
'=' expected near 'mt'
```

using this statement

```
print(i,j,mt([i][j]))
```

gives this error

```
unexpected symbol near '['
```

I did read this thread
[How do I display array elements in Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274380/how-do-i-display-array-elements-in-lua)

but my question is more fundamental about the proper syntax.

Comment: `print mt([i][j])` should be `print(mt[i][j])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the opening parenthesis should be immediatly following **Print** not after the **mt**, You need to move the parenthesis, resulting in the code for that line:

```
print(mt[i][j])
```

Making the complete code snippet be:

```
mt = {}          -- create the matrix
for i=1,5 do
 mt[i] = {}     -- create a new row
  for j=1,3 do
    mt[i][j] = j
    print(i,j)
    print (mt[i][j])
  end
end
```

You probably Made a simple typo, but if not, the explanation (as you probably know) is that the function **print()** is passed the argument **mt[i][j]**, the  **mt** (the variable) is part of the argument too.

Comment: thank you. and it turns out LUA does not like parens around the indices. this fails:print(i,j,(mt([i][j]))) but this works print(i,j,(mt[i][j]))

Comment: `mt([i][j])` means "call a function stored in the variable named `mt`", but has a syntax error because the first table index operator `[]` encountered has no table to index. Lua (**not LUA**) syntax is remarkably consistent and easy to learn. I strongly recommend starting at [www.lua.org](http://www.lua.org/docs.html) and doing some reading on the basics. The full text of the Lua 5.0 edition of the book [*Programming in Lua*](http://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html) is there, and is well worth time spent on it.